# Could not chdir to home directory when create and login a new user?

Tags: permissions

I'm a new user of CentOS and now I want to create a new user of my system and let it can only access one directory.

First I create a group named `test`.

Then:

```
useradd -g test -d /home/disk/disk1/testDir testuser
```

The `disk1` is a real disk which is mounted in disk1 folder.

And now I can see the `testDir` folder and its `ll` output is :

```
drwx------ 2 testuser test  4096 Jul 27 14:48 testDir
```

And after I set the password and login with `testuser` by `putty`. It says:

```
Could not chdir to home directory /home/disk/disk1/testDir: Permission denied
```

The folder exists and owned by `testuser`. I do not understand why it got permission denied?

Comment: What `ls -ld /home/disk` and `ls -ld /home/disk/disk1` return?

Comment: @cuonglm Thanks, I find /home/disk is belong to other user. Plz post your answer and I will accept it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you can not access to the directory you have right permissions, the first thing you should check is your access rights with parent directories:

```
ls -ld /home/disk
```

and:

```
ls -ld /home/disk/disk1
```

You need at least execute permission to access the child of those directories.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, on a RHEL6.5 install, the two-up directory permissions prevented login:

```
% ssh dvpsmf
blah@dvpsmf.test.com.au's password: 
Last login: Wed Feb  3 11:08:03 2016 from 10.14.107.212
Could not chdir to home directory /osp/local/home/blah: Permission denied 
$ 
$ ls -ld --context / /osp /osp/local /osp/local/home
ls: cannot access /osp/local/home: Permission denied
dr-xr-xr-x. root  root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0      /
drwxr-xr-x. root  root system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0 /osp
drwxr-x---  abcde osp  ?                                /osp/local
$
$ sudo ls -ld --context / /osp /osp/local /osp/local/home
dr-xr-xr-x. root  root system_u:object_r:root_t:s0      /
drwxr-xr-x. root  root system_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0 /osp
drwxr-x---  abcde osp  ?                                /osp/local
drwxr-x---  abcde in   ?                                /osp/local/home
$
```

User was already member of group in - adding to group osp fixed login